Updating filter value on embed quicksight dashboard throwing error
When attempting to update the filter group value using embeddedDashboardExperience.updateFilterGroups, an error with the code "INVALID_INPUT" is being returned.
I am using amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk version 2.6.0
Referred from https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-quicksight-embedding-sdk/blob/master/README.md#-updatefiltergroups-filtergroups-filtergroup--promiseresponsemessage
embeddedDashboardExperience.updateFilterGroups([
        {
            FilterGroupId: 'xxxxxxx',
            Filters: [
                {
                  CategoryFilter: {
                        Column: {
                            ColumnName: 'Order',
                            DataSetIdentifier: 'dw -hourly (o)'
                        },
                        FilterId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
                        MatchOperator: 'CONTAINS',
                        NullOption: 'NON_NULLS_ONLY',
                        CategoryValues: ['Pickup']
                    }
                }
            ],
            ScopeConfiguration: {
                SelectedSheets: {
                    SheetVisualScopingConfigurations: [
                        {
                            Scope: 'ALL_VISUALS',
                            SheetId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            CrossDataset: 'ALL_DATASETS',
            Status: 'ENABLED'
        }
    ]);

